# Questions on surfaceview creation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a question with surfaceview creation. I have practically read through most of the discussions related to this topic but none of them fit into my scenario. My apk is a bit special. Due to some special reason, I need to create the Relativelayout dynamically. Not via layout xml file and then R.layouout. I have extracted my code into a simple app to illustrate my problem.

I have 2 files namely MainActivity.java and BrowserView.java. In MainActivity.java, I will create a BrowserView. This class implements the surfaceview.

I have tried setting breakpoints in both surfaceCreated and surfaceChanged but so far none of these events come which inmplies that my surface creation is not successful. Is there anything I have missed?

Is my concept in surfaceview creation correct? Any suggestions or any problems you could spot in my code? Many thanks!

1. Create Relativelayout
2. Create surfaceview (i.e. BrowserView as it extends surfaceview)
3. Addview BrowserView to the Relativelayout
4. In BrowserView, setFocus and addcallback

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {  

    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = null;  
    private BrowserView mBrowserView = null;  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    mRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);  
    setContentView(mRelativeLayout);  

    mBrowserView = new BrowserView(this);  

    // I did this because some discussion suggested that height and 
    //width should not be 0  
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams                         (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);  
lp.height = 130;  
lp.width = 508;  

    mRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);  
    mRelativeLayout.addView(mBrowserView, lp);  
}  


@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  
    return true;  
}  

@Override  
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will  
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long  
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.  
    int id = item.getItemId();  
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {  
        return true;  
    }  
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
}
```

}

### BrowserView.java

```
public class BrowserView extends SurfaceView implements   SurfaceHolder.Callback {  

public BrowserView(Context context) {  
    super(context);  
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub  

    // make sure we get key events  
    setFocusable(true);  
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  
    requestFocus();  


    // make sure we get surface events  
    getHolder().addCallback(this);  

    // make sure that we support transparency  
    setZOrderOnTop(true);  
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);  


}  

@Override  
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Log.d("BrowserView", "surfaceCreated");  

}  

@Override  
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Log.d("BrowserView", "surfaceChanged");  
}  

@Override  
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Log.d("BrowserView", "surfaceDestroyed");  
}  

@Override  
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)  
{  
    Rect windowRect = new Rect();  
    getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowRect);  

    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);  
    int height = Math.min(MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec),   windowRect.bottom);  

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the OnCreate function move the call to setContentView(mRelativeLayout) to the end of the function, after you have added the BrowserView into the relative layout.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: My apology. My first few tries didn't work but after I did something, it started to work. The thing is this...as suggested, I moved the setContentView to the last line of the function. After that I run my code in debugging mode it didn't work so being a bit impatient,I hit the spacebar of my tablet (I have a Asus Transformer tablet with a detachable keyboard connected via USB to my laptop), the sufraceCreated came. Is there any specific reason why I need to hit the spacebar for the event to come? Why can't it come automatically? My program cannot have user intervention.

Comment: @angelfire I added the code into a project to run it and was unable to reproduce the delay with surfaceCreated() being called.